# Fix background on mobile for non RWD site

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've had this problem in the past but at the moment i am unable to find the right fix.

We built this huge site over a year ago. At the time RWD was not even considered and it was out of scope.

Now, there are some minor issues the client want us to look into, so that the site doesn't look as bad on mobile devices.

The site in question is www.bombardier.com ( preview using a mobile device ). Basically the main thing that needs fixing is the backgrounds not covering 100% of the screen. They, correctly stay at would be the normal screen size, but because the content is much wider and not responsive, the page appears much larger while the main backgrounds ( body, header and footer ) appear to be cut short.

Any suggestions on how to make this look nicer ?

Thx.

Comment: Why the negative votes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your site has a fixed width of 960px all you need to do is add...

```
body {
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

... this will prevent the `body` from shrinking down the the viewport width and cutting off you background on small screens.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn, may I ask you to have a look at a responsive design related question here : http://tinyurl.com/nadfh2u ?